# GraphQL: How to handle referencing a type within its own type definition?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server, graphql-js

Say I have the following:

```
type User {
  id: Int!
  name: String
  dob: String
  friends: [User]
}

Query {
  user(id: Int!): User
}
```

Looks to me like I just created the potential for infinite recursion:

```
query GetUser($userId: Int!) {
  user(id: $userId) {
    friends {
      name
      friends {
        name
        friends {
          name
          ...etc
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

How would I guard against this is in my `user` resolver?

Comment: It's not infinite recursion because your query only loads three nested levels, not an infinite number. Could you clarify what specifically are you concerned about?

Comment: usually max depth level/complexity cost is calculated/limited - not defined in type system at all - implementation related details

Answer (score 1):

This could be a potential problem, but you can use custom validation to prevent those kind of requests, e.g.
https://github.com/stems/graphql-depth-limit

```
import depthLimit from 'graphql-depth-limit'
import express from 'express'
import graphqlHTTP from 'express-graphql'
import schema from './schema'

const app = express()

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP((req, res) => ({
  schema,
  validationRules: [ depthLimit(10) ]
})))
```